# Azure Web Test - Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel when using CloudFlare SSL

Tags: azure, ssl, cloudflare

I have an Azure Website and have a continuous web test setup. The web test runs successfully for an entire hour, but then fails at the same time each hour (minute 3 to be exact) with the following exception:

```
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.WebTestTransaction.ResponseReceived(IAsyncResult result)
```

The weird thing is this error only seems to occur when using CloudFlare in front of the Azure Website. As soon as I "pause" CloudFlare, I no longer get the exception. I checked the difference in the certs in Chrome and the cert from cloudflare is using AES_128_GCM and ECDHE_ECDSA (Chrome labels as up to date cryptography) while the cert I installed on the website in Azure uses AES_256_CBC / SHA1 / RSA (which Chrome labels obsolete) -- both are using TLS 1.2.

I found this post that is very similar (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/91e37c9e-e15e-444b-bffb-c221df388692/synthetic-monitors-availability-could-not-create-ssltls-secure-channel?forum=ApplicationInsights) and even replied to the thread to see if there have been any updates. Based on that post, it seems like it's an issue with the tools Microsoft is using as part of Application Insights, but mine is only happening once every hour on a regular interval and it works fine at all other times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the same issue discussed on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ca6372be-3169-4fb5-870f-bfbea605faf6/azure-webapp-webjob-exception-could-not-create-ssltls-secure-channel?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview. You may want to monitor that thread.

Comment: Thanks, David. That is the same issue and it's got traction from someone from Microsoft - hopefully they come up with something!

Comment: And that someone is you! :)